# Trying to set fileinput val from drag and drop Jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a simple uploader where users drag and drop files from the desktop into the website element. I believe I figured out how but I cant seem to get any information on the file. How can I set a file inputs value from a drag and drop? Here is the drag and drop code im not sure if its correct. The box does change color when draged over thats about it.

```
$(".droparea").bind({
  dragleave: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            $(".droparea").css("backgroundColor","white");


            },
            drop: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
//something here to set the FileInput element val()
                           },
            dragenter: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
               $(".droparea").css("backgroundColor","Green");
            },
            dragover: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTML5 their is a great [tutorial here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-selecting-files-dnd). You can just maybe convert them to jQuery as it seems you're using jQuery for your example.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/